# What is temp and what is the use of temp in java?

Tags: java

I am getting started to learn Java and I wrote a simple array example program,

```
public class ExampleArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        System.out.println(a[2] + " " + a[4]);
        for (int temp : a) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
30 50
10
20
30
40
50
```

It prints all the values from an array.

May I know, what is the use of `temp` in Java?

Can anyone explain this keyword please?

Comment: temp is a local variable name .read enhanced for loop http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/enhanced-for-loops.html

Comment: Look for `for-each loop in Java`!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: I advise ramping up your approach to learning Java from haplesssly trying to understand random code to working through some book or online tutorial. I suggest Oracle's own tutorials.

Comment: ok @FastSnail.. what is this use? used for prints all the value from an array?

Comment: can you show me that link please @MarkoTopolnik

Comment: @selva assign one number to temp variable from array which contain bunch of numbers and then print .finally all numbers get printed .but only one one time

Comment: Use Google Search to find it. Try "oracle java tutorial".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`temp` is not a keyword, it is just a name for a local variable. You can call it `temp`, `blub` or better: `entry` or `value` (to have a meaningful name for this variable).

`for(int temp: a)` means literally: take each element from array (or any other `Iterable`) `a` separately and write it in the variable `temp` of type `int`, so the loop body can use that variable  / array element.
The code in your example then use this variable to print it to the console.

Comment: can i know, difference between temp and a in my program?

Comment: `a` is your array `int a[] = {10,20,30,40,50};` that contains these specified elements. `temp` is a variable that contains one single element of that array in your loop. In the first "round", it will be `10`, in he next one it will tbe `20` and so on. So `a` is the whole storage and `temp` just a single element of it. Btw: `temp` changes its value due to the usage in a `for-each` loop. If you would write `int temp = a[0]` instead, then it will be the first element (i.e. `10` on index `0`) and it won't change its value.

Answer (score 2):

Here `temp` is nothing but a variable, which used to iterate the value of the array `a`.Which get the values one by one from array.This is actually happening there

```
for(Iterator<String> temp = someList.iterator(); temp.hasNext(); ) {
    String item = temp.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

FYI: There is no need of using a name `temp`, Its a variable you can use as you wish and there is nothing called `temp` there in java.You can use any java variable name.

Answer (score 2):

`temp` in this case is the name of a local variable (an integer).

```java
for(int temp : a){
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

This code iterates through the array named `a`. In each iteration `temp` gets assigned the next value of `a`. `System.out.println(temp);` just prints the value of `temp` to the console.